# jquery easyui loading components via ajax (not data, real ui components)

Tags: jquery-easyui

I am using jquery easyui with angularjs.
I am loading a form template (via ajax) with a lot of components inside.
this is the form coming from ajax:

```
 <form id="LoginForm" method="post" ng-submit="login()">
     <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="easyui-linkbutton"  nclick="submitForm()">Submit</a>
</form>
```

this is how I render it right after the ajax call:

```
$("#LoginForm").form();
```

The problem is that all the form sub components are not becoming easyui widjets and i need to go over each and every one and make it live (after they came from ajax).
for example, I need to render the form and it button in order to make it a widjet...

```
$('#LoginForm').form('reset');
$('#LoginForm a').linkbutton();
```

Is there any easyui to re-render the components, something like:

```
$('#LoginForm').render();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found it:

```
$.parser.parse('#LoginForm');
```